# Fama-Macbeth cross-sectional regression interpretation

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have applied Fama-Macbeth cross-sectional regression on Fama and French five-factor model (2014). On the left-hand side are the portfolio returns for sixteen size - B/M portfolios. On the right-hand-side are five the factors i.e. market, size, investment, and profitability factor.

The issue I am facing is that in 16-time series regressions, my intercepts were all positive and significant. Factor loadings for each factor were also strong and significant. However, when I applied t cross-section regressions (3439 days), the intercept of cross-section regression turned out to be negative and insignificant. Also, the risk premiums are very small (down to 4 decimal points).

Kindly help me make sense out of this.

Edit: I have added cross-section regression statistics as an example.On the left-hand side were portfolio returns of sixteen size - profitability sorted portfolios (4 x 4 portfolio design). On the right-hand side were the betas of market, size, profitability and investment factors obtained from time-series regression.

I am also providing the intercepts obtained from time-series regression.

[image: cross-section regression]

[image: Time-series regression intercepts]

Comment: With this kind of interpretation question, it's often helpful if you can paste in the output from your regressions.

Comment: thank you, I have added the results that are highlighting my problem.